# How to edit rpm's HEADER and NAME-VERSION-RELEASE

Tags: package-management, rpm

Is there's a way or a tool that can modify the `HEADER` and the `NAME-VERSION-RELEASE` for an existing `rpm` without installing/rebuilding it?

Comment: Generally, this is not recommended practice. I use scripts based on `rpmrebuild` for manual tweaks to custom-built packages. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have some rpms and it's automatically created by our hudson machine but I wanted to edit the HEADER and the NAME-VERSION-RELEASE to insert the details of what number of rebuild the rpms is.

can you include the details how you edit those info without needing the rebuilding the rpm?

Comment: I only know how to rebuild with editing in one's favorite editor (`export EDITOR=emacs`): `rpmrebuild -e -n -d . PACKAGE_NAME`. You can always install the RPM afterwards if editing was successful: `yum install PACKAGE.rpm`.